# Transfer data from view to controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass all the data to the HttpPost 'index' method, but it's not working properly.

My view looks like that:

```
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <select class="selectStyled" id="SelectBranch">
        @{
            var branches = Model.Select(x => x.Branch1).Distinct().ToList();
        }
        <option value="">Pick-up location</option>
        @foreach (var i in branches)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i</option>
        }
    </select>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick Up Date" id="txtboxPickup" />
    <input type="time" />

    <input type="text" placeholder="Drop Off Date" id="txtboxDropoff" />
    <input type="time" />
    <input class="buttonStyle" style="background-color:white; color:black" type="submit" value="Search" />
}
</body>
```

My model:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcProject.Branch>
```

In the controller I have two methods:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Branch> arr = me.Branches.ToList();
        return View(arr);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Branch b)
    {
        ///////////
        //////////
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You should provide Branch definition

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics, in particular how to generate your view using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods. Your manual inputs don't even have `name` attributes so nothing is submitted, and the model in the view is `IEnumerable<Branch>` which mean your POST method parameter need to be `IEnumerable<Branch>`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, in Index action you want to pass three values: branch, pickup, dropoff values. Better way to do that

1) Create model

```
public class BranchPostModel 
{
public int BranchId {get;set;}
public string Pickup {get;set;}
public string Dropoff{get;set;}
}
```

2) Change yout post Index action to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(BranchPostModel model)
{
    ///////////
    Branch b = me.Branches.First(i=>i.Id == model.BranchId);
    var pickup = model.Pickup;
    var dropoff = model.Dropoff;
    //////////
    return View();
}
```

3) Put proper names to your inputs/select in your View. Name of your inputs in HTML should match the name of your properties inside your BranchPostModel

```
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <select class="selectStyled" name="BranchId" id="SelectBranch">
        @{
            var branches = Model.Select(x => x.Branch1).Distinct().ToList();
        }
        <option value="">Pick-up location</option>
        @foreach (var i in branches)
        {
            <option value="@i">@i</option>
        }
    </select>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick Up Date" name="Pickup" id="txtboxPickup" />
    <input type="time" />

    <input type="text" placeholder="Drop Off Date" name="Dropoff" id="txtboxDropoff" />
    <input type="time" />
    <input class="buttonStyle" style="background-color:white; color:black" type="submit" value="Search" />
}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Ajax method. It helps to pass any data into corresponding Action

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ControllerName","test")',
    data: {data: item},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        Alert("Data passed Sucessfully");
    }
});
```